# PHP Trying to test my local server using PHP, the local server never accepts the connection

Tags: php, .net, tcp

I'm trying to make a simple chat server.

I was using html forms to test it. Now I want to see if it really works by creating some PHP scrips and have a bunch of them running at the same time.

I'm using curl to immolate a post. When I try to send a post message to my chat server the accept never goes off. But if I submit my form, it sees it.

server code

```
server = new ServerSocket(1079); // port 62
// Loop forever
while(true)
{
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // get a new connection
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    System.out.println("Aceepting connections on port 1030 \r");

    try{
        // Get New Connection

        // wait for ever on accepting new connections
        server.setSoTimeout(0);  
        connection = server.accept();

        cConnection thread = new cConnection("thread3", connection);
```

PHP Script:

```
extract($_POST);

//set POST variables
$url = 'http://localhost:1079/enter';
$fields = array(
            'username'=>urlencod("tedpottel"),
            'password'=>urlencode("oreo8157"),
            'comment'=>urlencode("new comment"),
        );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key => $value) {
    $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
}
rtrim($fields_string,'&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print $result;
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

HTML Form

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="http://localhost:1079/enter">
            <input name="username" type="text" value="tedpottel" />
            <input name="password" type="text" value="oreo8157" />
            <input name="comment" type="text" value="Hi There" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You create a server socket on port 1079, you comment it as port 62 and print that the server is listening on port 1030. WHAT?

Comment: FYI you can change the code that does `//url-ify the data for the POST
` to a simple call to [http_build_query](http://www.php.net/http_build_query) `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discrepancies pointed out in previous comment, I have to believe that you did simply copy-paste this (and why would you do anything else?). Therefore in your PHP script, here is a mistake:

```
'username'=>urlencod("tedpottel")
```

You meant to write **urlencode**. But I don't think this would cause the server.accept() to not respond.

I'm amused by your use of "immolate" when you meant "imitate".

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, yes the code was copied, but i did change the url to point to my web server.  It worked fine. And yes I cannot spell.